# Addition operators not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make one-page scrolling but I have a small problem. I have

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){   
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
    var top = -main.offsetTop;
    main.style.top = -100 + '%';        
});
```

Now this only works once obviously, so I'm trying to put an addition operator so it deducts a 100% every time you scroll.

```
    main.style.top -= 100 + '%';
```

but that doesn't work for some reason..

Addition works if I do this instead...

```
    var top = main.offsetTop;
    main.style.top = top - 100 + '%';
```

but this fucks things up since top is technically in px not %. So any ideas how to make **main.style.top -= 100 + '%';** work or a good alternative instead?

Comment: You can't do subtraction or addition or string values. Which is what `.style.top` is. One of many possible solutions is to use `parseInt()` to get just the number part, do the maths operation on *that*, then concatenate `"%"` on the end of the result.

Comment: what are you trying to do??

Comment: main.style.top -= 100 + '%' doesn't work as you expect because the right side evaluates to a string '100%'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write the expression `main.style.top -= 100 + '%';` in another way that means the same thing:

```
main.style.top -= (100 + '%' /* this is a string now */)
```

What happens if you -= a string from anything? The first expression that you put (`main.style.top = top - 100 + '%';`) was closer to what you want but still not right. If you want to subtract 100% of the top value every time, like you said you need to do it in terms of pixels, not percent. So first you need to find how many pixels is 100 percent, which looking at your code might just be the value of `main.offsetTop` for you. Then you need to subtract that value from the top value. So what you have first is close but I think you need:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){   
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
  var top = main.offsetTop;
  main.style.top -= top;       
});
```